# what is the expected number of car thefts occurring on any particular day?

Tags: probability

[image]

is $0\times 0.10 + 1\times 0.35 + 2 \times 0.30 + 3 \times 0.08 + 4\times 0.15 + 5 \times 0.02= 5.15$ the right answer?

Answer (score 1):

You need to redo the calculations since :
$$0\times 0.10 + 1\times 0.35 + 2 \times 0.30 + 3 \times 0.08 + 4\times 0.15 + 5 \times 0.02= 1.89$$
Hence, the expected number of car thefts $= 1.89$ cars per day.